# How does one open a documentFragment in a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What options are there for opening a document fragment in a new tab or window. Which are most browser compatible and which are most user friendly?

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var div = $("<div>").addClass("Printable");
div[0].innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML;
frag.appendChild(div[0]);
openIt(frag); // How to implement openIt
```

The fragment contains a reformatted subset of the page that is ready to be printed.

Preferably I would like it to open naturally through some kind `<link>` or `<a>` and look like any other user friendly html link, rather then quietly opening up an annoying pop-up through `window.open`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reliably do this *without* `window.open()` and even then you need to create the fragment on *that* `document`, rather than the current (as some browsers don't allow cross-appending elements.  It would look something like this:

```
var win = window.open("","myWindow","...options...");
var frag = win.document.createDocumentFragment();
var div = win.document.createElement("div");
div.className = "Printable";
div.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML;
frag.appendChild(div);
```

[You can test out a demo here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/KV59Y/).

Comment: even if that works, most (if not all?) browsers can get configured whether `window.open()` opens a new tab or a popup window.

Comment: @jAndy - I agree, but you're talking about cross-document manipulation, you only have a limited number of options here...

Comment: I was really hoping to avoid using `window.open`

Comment: @Raynos - Unfortunately, if you want cross-browser support (I can't for the life of me remember which all block cross-document element posting, but it's IE IIRC) you *have* to go this route, the other simply won't work everywhere.

Comment: @Raynos - you have to allow popups (since it's not invoked as the result of a click) but sure it does, you left out a line from my demo that creates the body: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/KV59Y/

Answer (score 2):

Try this.
`window.open('data:text/html;charset=utf-8,text%20to%20show');`

edited:

That was the basic ...
This should suit your needs:

```
var text = "<div class='Printable'>" + $("body").html() + "</div>";
window.open('data:text/html;charset=utf-8,'+text);
```

Comment: That has absolutely no reference to the document fragment.

Comment: I think he meant the document fragment text as `text to show` parameter.

Comment: @rahul I'm sure text to show is a string. and converting the documentFragment's content to a string ruins its formatting.

Comment: @UVL I see. I didn't realise you meant to pass HTML in directly.